# Displaying Switch Value in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui, formik

I have a very simple problem in my react app. I need to turn on the switch value if it is true otherwise false. I already initialize the value as true but the switch is still off.

Pls check this code-sandbox link

[CLICK THIS](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-knz3q?file=/demo.js:4185-5018)

```html
<Grid item xs="{12}" md="{6}">
  <FormControlLabel
    name="buy"
    variant="outlined"
    value="{values.buy}"
    onChange="{handleChange}"
    onBlur="{handleBlur}"
    control="{<Switch"
    color="primary"
  />} label="Triage?" labelPlacement="end" style={{ display: "flex",
  justifyContent: "flex-end" }} />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Isn't that `checked` property responsible for the switch state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The on/off state of the switch is controlled by property 'checked'. You can set it in both FormControlLabel and Switch components.

Here's the code for setting it in the FormControlLabel:

```
<Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
                <FormControlLabel
                  name="buy"
                  variant="outlined"
                  value={values.buy}
                  checked={values.buy}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  onBlur={handleBlur}
                  control={<Switch color="primary" />}
                  label="Triage?"
                  labelPlacement="end"
                  style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "flex-end" }}
                />
              </Grid>
```

Here's the second option, to set it in Switch:

```
<Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
                <FormControlLabel
                  name="buy"
                  variant="outlined"
                  value={values.buy}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  onBlur={handleBlur}
                  control={<Switch color="primary" checked={values.buy} />}
                  label="Triage?"
                  labelPlacement="end"
                  style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "flex-end" }}
                />
              </Grid>
```

Both seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `checked` property

```
...
<Switch checked={values.buy} color="primary" />
```

**UPDATE**

To be precise: add `checked` in the place where you pass the `Switch` control. All other code should not be touched

```
... your code
control={<Switch checked={values.buy} color="primary" />}
... your code
```

Comment: How about the other properties? value={values.buy}
                      onChange={handleChange}
                      onBlur={handleBlur}. Should i transfer them inside the <Switch>?

Comment: @Robert : simply change `value` for `checked` in your current code